# Where can I find style guide for metro UI for web applications?

Tags: guidelines, standards, style, windows-phone-7, metro

I am interested in the Metro UI that microsoft has used for windows phone 7 for web. I see that their site microsoft.com has been done with metro UI recently.

I am looking for a style guide and resources that I can use to build a web app based on the metro UI.

Comment: Please note that I am not looking to build wp7 apps. I am trying to adapt the metro UI theme to web apps.

Answer (score 31):

[User Experience Design Guidelines for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/fa00461b-abe1-41d1-be87-0b0fe3d3389d%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Related:
[Windows Phone UI and Design Language](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX10/CL14) on Channel 9 (video)

Comment: @jin, no problem; according to the date, it happened this month.

Comment: As soon as I started to read the first sentence on that page, I was interrupted by a "MSDN user opinion survey" animated dialog that panned in from the top and stopped in the middle of the page.

Answer (score 10):

May you have a look at Jeff Wilcox' "Metro" Design Guide for Developers: http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/03/metro-design-guide-v1/

This guide is not as extensive as the PDF provided bye @Jin, but focuses on some main aspects to consider, when developing WP7 Apps.

Answer (score 4):

For a quick look, Jeff Wilcox's ["Metro" Design Guide](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/03/metro-design-guide-v1/) is good.

If you want to see an after-action report, [Scott Barnes](http://www.riagenic.com/archives/526) wrote about his experiences with Metro.

The comprehensive manual titled [Windows Phone 7 Series UI Design & Interaction Guide](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=183218) is also available.

You may find the [Channel 9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX10/CL14) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

**Update #1**: This project is discontinued you can see how it looked like at http://www.youtube.com/metrodynamis

[Metro Dynamis](http://metrodynamis.com) is a UX Framework for Metro Style Applications in HTML/CSS/Javascript

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of Metro Dynamis.

Answer (score 3):

You may find this documentation from Microsoft helpful:
Downloading design assets for Metro style apps
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700403

Also, I created a simple Windows 8 Metro mockup PSD available for download here:
http://dribbble.com/shots/301642-Windows-8-Metro-UI-Demo-PSD

Comment: That's stencils not style guides.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a list of metro-style websites for some inspiration: http://teusje.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/web-design-trend-metro-ui/

Also, you can take a look to [this templating framework](http://metro-webdesign.tk/) to create websites styled like Metro UI.

Comment: The OP was requesting resources and style guidelines, not a list of examples of Metro sites and an undisclosed link to your own site. If you're referring to your own site in an answer then it's not cool to pretend it's just something you found. If it's relevant then disclose that you have a site that answers the OPs question.

Answer (score 2):

[5 Things you ought to know when designing metro screens.](http://www.riagenic.com/archives/526)

Answer (score 1):

I found this article for an app I was working on: [Everything You Need To Create Windows 8 Metro UI-Styled Websites](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/everything-you-need-to-create-windows-8-metro-ui-styled-websites/)

Comment: Hi @Fiddy and welcome to UX.SE. Maybe you could elaborate a little on the answer. What can you expect in the guide etc.