# Windows 8 Metro Design Examples / Guidelines

Tags: metro, windows-8, windows-os

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find style guide for metro UI for web applications?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7219/where-can-i-find-style-guide-for-metro-ui-for-web-applications)

Not a technical question about *how* to build an app (I'm just going to use [DevExpress Tiles](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Tile/), mostly because I'm using a bunch of the other components in DevExpress and this seems to be another nice modern component to use)...  but more a question of how a Metro app should look and feel?

There's tons of "traditional" apps out there that have solved lots of problems for how various apps should look and work but being a technical person with no creative talent at all, i'm having real trouble visualising how I want my app to look and how one might interact with it in a Tiles world.

Crudely speaking, once the app is started you can configure it or connect to a server.

Once connected to a server you can disconnect, configuration of both the client and server, along with numerous functions that bring up a different UI - the different UI's are a totally different style of UI more akin to a CAD plan so i'm not fussed about that, it's really a question of trying to understand...:

a) is tiles even worth looking at? or using a component for the sake of it? OR would it give a nice modern fresh look to the very start of the app?
b) do you go from one tile control to another, OR would you add and remove tiles programmatically - i.e. in the example i've given, i'd start with two tiles and when you have connected, I could then add all the interface tiles in a new group and perhaps change the connect tile to a disconnect one etc?

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: Also check: http://windows8designhandbook.com

Answer (score 4):

Its still in work and not complete yet, but you can get some information here:

- [Windows Dev Center - Designing Metro style apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465427)
- [Windows Dev Center - Choosing the right UI surfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465304)
- [Windows Dev Center - Guidelines for user interaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465370.aspx)
- [Channel 9 Windows 8 UX Video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/BPS-1004)

Comment: Also check: http://windows8designhandbook.com

Answer (score 1):

- [Blendinsider Guide](http://blendinsider.com/technical/ux-guidelines-for-metro-style-app-development-2011-10-21/)
- [On Slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/davidwkchen/metro-ui-interaction-design-guidelines-microsoft-techdays-2011) This one is for Windows Mobile but might give you some insight.

Perhaps you can get more resource once we have final release of Windows 8.